# photoshop make border background black

Tags: adobe-photoshop, background, background-removal

here is my image:

[image]

You can't see it but there is a white border surrounding this image. What I want is to remove the white border and make it either disappear or turn black.

I'm fairly new to design and photoshop so please let me know if theres anything you need.

Comment: Crop it out or make a selection (and invert it) and fill it with black... Have you tried either of these methods?

Comment: I voted this down for several reasons. 1- please specify what type of original file you are working with (if it is not actually the PNG file above). 2- please specify what you have tried already. 3- the title is not a question. Honestly, what you are looking to do is _so remedial_ that a small amount of web searching could have produced many different ways to accomplish this simple task. Regardless, I will post an answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you want this image to retain its existing dimensions, there are several ways to accomplish what you are asking:

1. Draw a rectangle over the image, adjust the `Fill` to 0 and add a stroke a few pixels larger than the white space to cover and make sure the stroke is the same color as the image background. Adjust the size of the rectangle to extend beyond the canvas as well as cover the white area. `Save`.
2. Create a solid background layer of the same color as the dark background in your image- make sure it is below the image layer. Use the rectangle `marquee tool` to draw at or just inside the perimeter of the dark part of the image. Click the `Add a mask` button at the bottom of the Layers panel. `Save`. (Example below.)
3. Create a new layer above the image. Use the `Eye Dropper` tool to select the dark color of the image. Use the `Paintbrush Tool` to paint over the white border (freehand!). `Save`.

I'll stop here... hopefully you can get one of these to work.

[image]

[image]